# What to use for calling functions manually -> SELECT or EXEC?

Tags: sql-server

Why do I have to use a schema (dbo.xxx ) with scalar functions when using SELECT and not when using EXEC?

```
DECLARE @ReplicationGroup nvarchar(255) = 'Replication Configuration';
SELECT dbo.fnGetReplicationGroupID(@ReplicationGroup) -- Works but I have to keep dbo.
EXEC fnGetReplicationGroupID @ReplicationGroup -- Works without dbo.

select dbo.fnIsDebugLoggingEnabled(); -- Works but I have to keep dbo.
EXEC fnIsDebugLoggingEnabled  -- Works without dbo.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server has [3 different types of functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql): Scalar, Table-Valued, and Multi-Statement Table-Valued. Scalar functions may be used wherever a scalar expression is allowed as well as in an `EXECUTE` statement. Table-valued functions and Multi-Statement Table-Valued functions may be used wherever a table-valued expression is allowed, which does not include an `EXECUTE` statement. Examples:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnScalarFunctionExample(@value int)
RETURNS bit
AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN @value;
END;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnInlineTableValuedFunction (@value int)  
RETURNS TABLE  
AS  
RETURN   
(  
    SELECT @value AS Value  
);  
GO  

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnMultiStatementTableValuedFunction (@value int)  
RETURNS @Table TABLE   
(  
    Value int NOT NULL  
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(@value);
    RETURN;
END;
GO

--scalar functions can be called with EXEC or wherever in a scalar experession is permitted
DECLARE @ReturnValue int;
EXEC @ReturnValue = dbo.fnScalarFunctionExample 1;
PRINT @ReturnValue;
GO
SELECT dbo.fnScalarFunctionExample(1);
GO
SELECT 1 WHERE dbo.fnScalarFunctionExample(1) = 1;
GO

--table-valued functions are invoked from a SELECT query
SELECT * FROM dbo.fnInlineTableValuedFunction(1);
SELECT * FROM dbo.fnMultiStatementTableValuedFunction(1);  
GO
```

Syntactically, you specify parenthesis (empty if no parameters) when invoking functions with the exception of and `EXECUTE` statement. Parens are not specified with `EXECUTE` and parameters, if any, are supplied as named or positional parameters just like when executing a stored procedure.

I don't often see scalar functions invoked with `EXECUTE` in the wild since one can always use `SELECT` instead.

**EDIT**

It is necessary to (at least) schema-qualify scalar functions using 2-part names according to the documentation. As to why this is necessary, I think that is to avoid ambiguity with system functions that might have the same name.

Comment: I am trying to ask one more follow up question but it says..Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified

Comment: @SunMan, consider adding the additional question to your original post. It seems query question includes an at-sign, which is interpreted as a user reference in comments.

Comment: Ah.. I see...ok let me paste there